# $V$ is finitely generated $\iff V$ has a finite basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm preparing for exams, and thus I'm trying to improve my proof-writing. Is this one correct?

> $V$ is a vector space. $V$ finitely generated $\iff$ basis of $V$ is finite.

Denote $Sp$ the Span and let $v_1,...v_n$ $\in$ $V$ be vectors

We are going to make to cases

$\Leftarrow:$ Let there be a finite basis. By definition a basis is a linear independent set of vectors such that these vectors span the vector space. Thus take the basis $b_1,...,b_n$ and find $Sp(b_1,...,b_n)=V$. Edit: Thus finitely generated.

Lemma: For the other case we need to show a lemma. If $v_1,...,v_n$ are linearly dependent we can kick out a specific vector $v_i$ and we find $Sp(v_1,...v_i,...,v_n)=Sp(v_1,...,v_n)$. Edit: We need to be careful here because  we need to pick such a vector $v_i$ carefully, in other words, it holds not true for any random $v_i$.

We have $Sp(v_1,...,v_n) \subseteq Sp(v_1,...v_i,...,v_n)$ because pick $v \in Sp(v_1,...,v_n)$ we find $v=\alpha_1 v_1 +...+\alpha_n v_n=\alpha_1 v_1 +...+\alpha_n v_n+0 v_i$ by noticing we can simply insert $v_i$ and thus $v \in Sp(v_1,...,v_i,...,v_n)$.

The second case is more difficult namely: $Sp(v_1,...v_i,...,v_n) \subseteq Sp(v_1,...,v_n)$ Let $v \in Sp(v_1,...,v_i,...,v_n)$. We find due to the linear dependence and because of our assumption that there exists for at least one $\alpha$ nonzero a solution to $\alpha_1 v_1+ ... +\alpha_i v_i+...+\alpha_n v_n=0$. We will have for some $\alpha_i \neq 0$. This will be our smartly chosen $v_i$. We find $v_i=\beta_1 v_1 +...+\beta _n v_n$ for a specific $v_i$. Insert now this $v_i$ into $v=\alpha_1 v_1 +...\alpha_i v_i+...+\alpha_n v_n$ and we find $v=(\alpha_1 + \alpha_i \beta_1) v_1 +...+(\alpha_n +\alpha_i \beta_n) v_n$. Finally indeed $v \in Sp(v_1,...,v_n)$

$\Rightarrow$: Let $Sp(v_1,...,v_n)=V$. We are going to construct a basis out of these vector. $v_1,...,v_n$ are already generating but we need them to be linear independent in order to form a basis. We are going to use the following algorithm. Let $vectorList$ denote the list $v_1,...v_n$.

```
while(vectorList linear dependent){
    kick out a smartly chosen vector from vectorList
    //comment: due to our lemma the span is invariant and notice this only 
    works for a specific vector
}
```

Finally $vectorList$ form a basis due to linear independence, thus finite basis, which completes our proof. QED

Comment: Your idea is entirely correct. But you have to be careful with one detail: you can't just remove any $v_i$. You must remove a $v_i$ which satisfies $\alpha_i \ne 0$ in the linear combination $0 = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i u_i$. Otherwise your argument will not work. But it is always possible to find such an $u_i$ by smart choice. In a linear combination of $0$ in which not all $\alpha_i$ are zero there will always be at least two $\alpha_j \ne 0$. Choose one of the corresponding $u_j$ and you can use the argument you presented.

Comment: I was half-heartedly familiar with this fact, but upon closer reading, I realize that I have described it very confusingly (even theoretically wrong?)

Comment: I will make some edits to fix this(comment is just made in order to not make conversation obsolete)

Comment: Thank you for the comment and feedback

Comment: The Theorem you state is false. You specify $V$ and $v_1,\dots,v_n$ and then assert that is $\dim V$ is finite then these vectors span $V$. That need not be so, and in fact all you proved was that if $\dim V$ is finite THERE EXISTS some $b_1,b_2,\dots, b_n$ which span $V$. You need to edit the question to state the theorem correctly before we discuss proofs.

Comment: I eddited the theorem now how it is stated in my course. Do you mean the case $dim(V)=0$, for which the thm doesn't hold ture? I can't see the difference in meaning between some vectors span $V$ and there exists vectors that span $V$

Comment: Now I see... I made very unlucky formulations...